# Is it not possible to create a route for Azure IOT hub in the free trial?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azureportal

I'm trying to implement the IOT hub using Azure portal. This is the link from which I followed the instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/how-to-routing-portal?tabs=eventhubs .
So far, I have created an IOT hub and have registered a device with the help of instructions given in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal .

But when I try to add an endpoint to create a route, I'm unable to select any of the options (service bus queues, topics, event hubs, cosmos db, etc) from the endpoint the dropdown. The options are highlighted but I'm unable to select from the options. Any ideas on why I'm facing this issue? Could it be because I'm only using the free trial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible in the free trial. You might be facing a bug or trying to create a route when no endpoints are available. See the below screenshots (taken from a fresh Free tier IoT Hub)

In the message routing blade, you can add a route.
[image: Routes tab in IoT Hub]

If you can't select an endpoint, click 'Add endpoint' to create one.
[image: Adding a new route in IoT Hub]

Alternatively, you can add your custom endpoint in the custom endpoints tab first:
[image: Custom endpoints tab in IoT Hub]

If this doesn't work, try creating a new IoT Hub, yours might be facing an issue.